# Computing an integral using residues

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am trying to find an integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-\sqrt{(x^2 + 1)}}}{(x^2 + 1)^2}\,\mathrm dx$$

I went about applying contour integral over a semicircle with diameter along $ x = +\infty$ to  $- \infty $ enclosing the pole at  $x = +i $.  The residue is $(-i/2)$ as shown here.

So the integral should be $(2\pi i)\times (-i/2)=\pi$

However since it is a well behaved function if I do a quick numerical integration in Mathematica it is giving me a value of $0.475$

A plot confirms that the function converges very fast.

> **Mathematica code:**
>
> NIntegrate[  E^{- Sqrt[1 + y^2]}/(1 + y^2)^2, {y, -1000, 1000}]

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Well the integral is well less than $(1/e)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sqrt \pi /e <1.$ Why do you think the integral over the semi-circular arc $\to 0$ as $r \to \infty$?

Comment: Do you have to do it via residue theory? If you introduce $I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-a(x^2+1)}}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx$, and then differentiate twice, what do you get? (The end result will be non-elementary, but that does not depend on method of course)

Comment: Not really.   I do not have to do it via residue theory.  Will try your suggestion and see where it takes me.  Thanks!

Comment: Also just noticed that a square root is missing in the integral.  Edited it.

Comment: Then it becomes harder...

Comment: Well, I guess I will have to differentiate it four times then :)  Will get a bunch of undetermined constants.

Comment: But the resulting integral seems difficult. Probably one of the gurus will help you out :)

Comment: Actually,  on second thought - if we do go by contour integral along a semicircle enclosing the poles shouldn't the integral do tend to zero along the curve as the radius of the curve tend to infinity - after all we have an exponentially decaying term in the numerator and a R^3 in the denominator ?

Comment: With the square root you also have to be a bit careful with analyticity. The integral converges, no doubt about that, but what the function looks like when you take the step out in the complex plane, you have to analyse...

Answer (score 0):

The integral cannot be done by simply calculating residues since the function
$$f(z) = \frac{e^{-\sqrt{z^2 + 1}}}{(z^2 + 1)^2}$$
has poles *and* branch points at $z=\pm i$.
Here we analyze the integral using complex methods, properly taking the branch cut into account.
The development, and not the result (which depends on another difficult integral), is the point of this answer.

Consider
$$I(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\frac{e^{-\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}}{(x^2 + 1)^2}\, dx$$
where $a>1$.
In the spirit of the question, we have separated the poles and branch points. 
We let the branch cuts lie on the imaginary axis from $i a$ to $i\infty$ (and $-i a$ to $-i\infty$).
Thus,
$I(a) = \sum_{i=1}^6 I_i$, where
$$I_i = \int_{\Gamma_i}
\frac{e^{-\sqrt{z^2 + a^2}}}{(z^2 + 1)^2}\, dz,$$
where the $\Gamma_i$ are defined in the figure below.

One can show that $I_1,I_5\rightarrow 0$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$, where $R$ is the radius of the circular arc.
The residue can be found using standard methods.
Let
$$g(z) = \frac{e^{-\sqrt{z^2 + a^2}}}{(z^2 + 1)^2}.$$
We find
\begin{align*}
I_6 &= 2\pi i\,\mathrm{Res}_{z=i}g(z) \\
&= 2\pi i \left.\frac{d}{dz} \frac{e^{-\sqrt{z^2 + a^2}}}{(z+i)^2}\right|_{z=i} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\right)e^{-\sqrt{a^2-1}}.
\end{align*}

We parametrize the remaining integrals as follows: 
\begin{align*}
I_2:\quad & z = i a+ i t - \varepsilon, & t:\infty\rightarrow 0 \\
I_3:\quad & z = i a + \varepsilon e^{i\theta},  & \theta:\pi\rightarrow 2\pi \\
I_4:\quad & z = i a+ i t + \varepsilon, & t:\infty\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}
One finds that $I_3 \rightarrow 0$ as $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$.
$I_2$ and $I_4$ may be combined, with the result
\begin{align*}
I_2 + I_4 &= 2\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin\sqrt{t(t+2a)}}{((t+a)^2-1)^2}dt \\
&= 2\int_a^\infty \frac{\sin\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}{(u^2-1)^2}du.
    & (\textrm{Let }t=u-a.)
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
I(a) 
&= \frac{\pi}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\right)e^{-\sqrt{a^2-1}}
+ 2\int_a^\infty \frac{\sin\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}{(u^2-1)^2}dt. 
\end{align*}
Both terms diverge as $a\to 1$.
The divergent contributions can be shown to cancel leaving a finite part, the value of the original integral.

Aside: Note that if we let $x = \tan t$ we find the original integral is 
$$2\int_0^{\pi/2}e^{-\sec t}\cos^2 t\,dt.$$

[image]

Figure 1. Definition of $\Gamma_i$.